How to Integrate AWS X-Ray with Express Gateway Middleware?
I'm trying to integrate AWS X-Ray with an Express Gateway application to trace incoming HTTP requests and monitor performance. However, I am facing issues accessing the internal Express instance to attach the X-Ray middleware properly.
AWS X-Ray SDK Setup: I also tried the usual setup for AWS X-Ray by calling AWSXRay.captureHTTPsGlobal(require('http')) to capture HTTP traffic globally, but the traces are not appearing in the AWS X-Ray console.
What I’m Looking For:
A working solution to hook the AWS X-Ray middleware into Express Gateway’s internal Express app.
Any official method or best practice to add custom middleware for tracing in Express Gateway.
Code Example (What I've Tried):
const path = require("path");
const gateway = require("express-gateway");
const AWSXRay = require('aws-xray-sdk');
const nconf = require("nconf");
const { loadConfigurations } = require("./aws");

nconf.use('memory').env({ parseValues: true });

(async () => {
    await loadConfigurations();

    // Global capture of HTTP(S) requests with AWS X-Ray
    AWSXRay.captureHTTPsGlobal(require('http'));
    AWSXRay.captureHTTPsGlobal(require('https'));

    const gatewayInstance = gateway().load(path.join(__dirname, "config"));

    gatewayInstance.on('loaded', () => {
        const expressApp = gatewayInstance.app;  // Access the underlying Express app

        // Add AWS X-Ray middleware
        expressApp.use(AWSXRay.express.openSegment('appstore-gateway'));
        expressApp.use(AWSXRay.express.closeSegment());

        console.log('AWS X-Ray middleware applied.');
    });

    gatewayInstance.run();  // Start the Gateway
})();

Any help or insight into correctly hooking AWS X-Ray into Express Gateway would be greatly appreciated!

My understanding is that AWSXRay.express middleware is specifically for express package. It is not officially used to support node Express Gateway.
Otherwise, do you have the X-Ray Daemon running (required to send Segments to X-Ray).
